Centralizer of conjugacy classes
Let $\mathrm{G}$ be a complex reductive group and let $\mathrm{O}_g$ be the adjoint orbit of $g\in \mathrm{G}$.
I wonder is the centralizer $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{G}}(\mathrm{O}_g)$ still a reductive group in general? If not, how about the identity component of $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{G}}(\mathrm{O}_g)$?
In the case $g=\mathrm{I}$ the identity of $\mathrm{G}$, of course $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{G}}(\mathrm{O}_\mathrm{I})=\mathrm{G}$ is reductive. And for generic element $g\in \mathrm G$, its stabilizer is the maximal torus $\mathrm{T}$, and stabilizer of $hgh^{-1}$ for any $h\in \mathrm{G}$ should be $h\mathrm{T}h^{-1}$. Running through all $h\in \mathrm{G}$, we have the intersection of all $\{h\mathrm{T}h^{-1}\}_{h\in \mathrm{G}}=\mathrm{Z}(\mathrm G)$ is reductive. Any example except these two extreme cases will be helpful.

Your title refers to coadjoint orbits, but your body refers to conjugacy classes.  Was that intentional?

@LSpice Sorry it’s just a typo.

Re, OK, thanks. For some people (one of whom is me!), adjoint orbits are on the Lie algebra, and I'd refer to the group analogues as conjugacy classes. (Anyway the same question could be asked, and the same proof would work, on the Lie algebra, or the dual Lie algebra, so it's no big deal which one you meant.)

There is nothing special for these purposes about the complex numbers (except that all group schemes over it are smooth, which could simplify the argument slightly).  I'll work instead over an arbitrary field $k$.
Put $H = \operatorname C_G(G\cdot g)$.  I claim that $H$ is generated by the centre of $G$, and those almost-simple components $G'$ of $G$ such that the image of $g$ in the adjoint quotient of $G'$ is trivial.  Granting the claim, note that the subgroup $H'$ of $G$ generated by the maximal central torus in $G$, and the appropriate almost-simple subgroups of $G$, is the descent to $k$ of $(H_{\bar k})^\circ_\text{red}$—this is often phrased as "$\operatorname C_G(G\cdot g)^\circ$ is defined over $k$" in classical language where passing to reduced subschemes is left implicit.  It is clear that $H'$ is reductive, which I think may count as an answer to your question.
Since this claim is unaffected by passage to the algebraic closure of $k$, we may, and do, assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.
One containment is obvious.  Since, with hopefully obvious notation, the image of $H$ in $G_\text{ad}$ is contained in $\operatorname C_{G_\text{ad}}(G_\text{ad}\cdot g_\text{ad})$, it suffices to assume that $G$ is adjoint.  Then $G$ is the direct product of its simple factors, so $H$ admits a similar direct-product decomposition.  Thus it suffices to assume that $G$ is simple (as well as adjoint).
Now $\operatorname C_G(H)_\text{red}$ is a smooth, normal subgroup of $G$, hence is trivial or all of $G$ (because $G$ is simple).  If it is all of $G$, then $H$ is central, hence trivial.  Suppose that it is trivial.  Since $g$ belongs to $\operatorname C_G(H)(k) = \operatorname C_G(H)_\text{red}(k)$, this implies that $g$ is trivial, so that $H = \operatorname C_G(G\cdot g)$ is all of $G$.
